# Solving $y''+y = 3\sin(2t)+t\cos(2t)$ by undetermined coefficients

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I need to solve

$$y''+y = 3\sin(2t)+t\cos(2t)$$

by the method of undetermined coefficients. So I need first to find a solution to the non homogeneous equation. I'm using a theorem that says that I just need to find the solutions for:

$$y''+y = 3\sin(2t)$$
and
$$y''+y = t\cos(2t)$$

and them sum the two solutions. Then I just need to sum this final solution with the general solution for the homogeneous equation. The problem is that the answer in my book is the following:

$$y(t) = c_1\cos t+c_2\sin t-\frac{1}{t}t\cos 2t-\frac{5}{9}\sin 2t$$

but I solved $y''+y = 3\sin 2t$ and got $y=-\sin(2t)$, which is correct [according to wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27(t)%2By(t)%20%3D%203sin(2t)), so how does that $-\frac{5}{9}$ appeared?

Also, which should be the guess for the equation $y''+y = t\cos(2t)$? I'm gonna try $(at+b)(c\cos 2t + d\sin 2t)$, is it right? Because the derivatives are huge.

Please remember that I must use the method of undetermined coefficients.

Comment: @Moo why? What's wrong with my method?

Comment: @Moo my book says that if I find a particular solution for each equation, then I can sum the 2 and get a particular solution for the original equation. I can't see anything wrong with my method

Comment: @Moo I did exactly as you said: $y_{p1} = a\cos 2t+b\sin 2t$, and the answer was $y = -\sin 2t$, that's what I'm asking, because this is not $-\frac{5}{9}\sin 2t$ as in my book

Comment: So, what do you get when you try $(at+b)(c\cos{2t}+d\sin{2t})$ as a solution to $y''+y = t\cos(2t)$? Perhaps you will get a solution which contains $\frac{4}{9}\sin{2t}$, which, combined with the particular solution $y=-\sin{2t}$ you found earlier, gives the $-\frac{5}{9}\sin{2t}$ term that you are confused about.